# Встроить проверку кода Python в сайт

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование

Задача: есть сайт, на котором в поле можно ввести скрипты Python и нажать условную кнопку "Выполнить". Некий скрипт должен будет выполнить программу, подставив в неё тестовые данные и сверить полученные результаты с заданными.

В результате должна получиться сводка: время выполнения программы, количество используемой памяти, количество верных ответов (например, пройдено 8 из 10 тестов).

Должно быть похоже на https://informatics.msk.ru, где пользователи решают задачи и пишут код, отправляют в систему для проверки и получают заключение.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? Хотя бы что почитать по этому вопросу?

Comment: вариант трудный - openedx либо подобная платформа

Comment: вариант полегче - https://pyodide.org/en/stable/console.html

Comment: вариант непонятный по теме, но тоже рабочий и, возможно. наилучший -  jupyter

Comment: Не прошло и трёх лет. Спасибо большое за наводки :))